# Elm: understanding foldp and mouse-clicks

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I'm currently learning Elm. relatively new to functional programming. i'm trying to understand this example from http://elm-lang.org/learn/Using-Signals.elm on counting mouse-clicks. they provide the following code:

```
clickCount =
    foldp (\click count -> count + 1) 0 Mouse.clicks
```

They explain that foldp takes three arguments: a counter-incrementer, which we defined as an anonymous function with two inputs, a starting state 0, and the Mouse.clicks signal.

I do not understanding why we need the variable click in our anonymous function. Why can't we just have \count -> count + 1? Is the extra input getting bound to one of our inputs into foldp?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need it because `foldp` expects a function with two inputs.  In this case, the first input is just ignored by your lambda, but the `foldp` implementation still puts something in there.  `Mouse.clicks` always puts a sort of do-nothing value called `Unit` in there.

Some signals have a value associated with them, like `Mouse.position`, for example.  If you wanted to do something like measure how far the mouse has moved, you would need to use that parameter.

Comment: Ok, so the whatever function I send to foldp MUST have two inputs?

Comment: Yes, in that order.  The first is the value associated with the most recent signal, and the second is the accumulated state.

Comment: My Aha moment was recognizing this is as *reduce* in other languages.